# Disable multiple long-press gestures simultaneously

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` and i have multiple `UIImageView's` as its subview.
I have added `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to each of these subviews.
I handle this gesture in a method where i perform some animation on the sender `UIImageView`.

If I long press two `ImageView's` at a time, the animation gets disrupted.

Is there any way I can disable multiple long press gestures simultaneously? i.e allow only one 
`UIImageView` to detect LongPress gesture.

Comment: i guess Evgeniy Shurakov's suggestion are apt enough to solve ur query. let us knw if it helped u :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have actually several ways to solve your problem:

Set `exclusiveTouch` to YES for all your image views. It will block the delivery of touch events to other views in the same window.

Or you can set flag to ignore other recognizers when one of your recognizers move to Begin state.

Or you can disable gesture recognizers (UIGestureRecognizer has `enabled` property) except current one in your delegate method and enable all of them again when gesture finishes.

Comment: Thanks #Evgeniy Shurakov, the exclusiveTouch property works fine.

Answer (score 2):

We can also address the issue **if** we are using `TableViewController` and we want `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to operate on only one cell simultaneously.

First we will need to define a static var in the CustomCell:

```
static var isLongPressInProgress = false
```

and then in the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` which states if we can use the gesture:

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {        
    if let _ = gestureRecognizer as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
        if CustomCell.isLongPressInProgress == true {
          return false
        }
      return true
     }
  return false
 }
```

You will set the var `isLongPressInProgress` in the `case .Began:` to true and at the `case .Ended:` to false